# Can't re-open project files sidebar anymore in Atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor

Sorry if this is the wrong place to answer but I found no other community which could help me with this. I accidentally closed the left-sidebar that shows the currently open project and it's files. Not sure what it's called, maybe navigation, folder view, either way, I tried pressing nearly every key combination to no results. I tried searching in the command palette for something that looked like "open project sidebar" but nothing. Now I'm stuck having no idea how to restore my primary navigation means when working with Atom. I tried opening multiple projects but I just get a black screen without the project sidebar, like it was hidden.

Any ideas?

I'm talking about this sidebar:
[image]

Comment: It's called "Tree-view".
You should be able to enable it via command palette or `ctrl + ,`

Comment: thanks, just enabled it. Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: Added as an answer, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called "Tree-View".

You should be able to enable it via command pallete or `ctrl + ,`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS.  On Mac OS X, it's CMD-\ (Command-Backslash) to toggle it.  The option located on the View menu, called `Toggle Tree View` (the last menu option).